# Minus operation is working wrong

Tags: linux, bash

**My script is below:**

```
for i in {"CON","PA","PRO","RE","S","UN","VO"};
do
count=$(sqlplus -S $user/$pass<<EOF
    select count(distinct s.filename) as count
    from cd.tbl_1 s
    where s.dt like to_char(sysdate-1,'YYYYMMDD')||'%' and s.type='$i';
    exit;
    EOF)
yday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%b %_d")
thecount=$(ls . -ltr | grep "$yday" | wc -l)
echo $i" ON DB  $count DB files is lower than the number $((thecount-count)) files in folder
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
```

But interesting thins that `$thecount` and `$count` value is exactly same , so when i use minus operation like above, it has not 0 value and different value. So it doesn't minus correct. What is wrong in here ?

Comment: oops. looks like your greeting and "My script is below" got absorbed into your code. You can probably edit that.

Comment: Please consider accepting good answers for your questions. Since this question features code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34647893/5067311), I suspect you have some deficiencies in this area. And what is the result instead of 0? Are you sure that `$count$` is the same as `$thecount`?

Comment: 1. Be careful using `$`s in here docs: `s.type='$i'`. 2. I think you want this: `$(( $thecount - $count ))` (with inter-spacing). 3. Use `bash -x` or `set -x` in your script to debug it.

Comment: @Andras Deak, sorry did not click accept icon. now i did it. Yes, I am sure it's exactly same. i printed without minus operation. It was same.

Comment: @Harvey, i used yours and result is below.  
     COUNT
----------
      4438 DB files is lower than the number 8876 files in folder, hehe it's multi operation. It supposed to 0 not 8876.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found my mistake, 

count=$(sqlplus -S $user/$pass<<EOF
    select count(distinct s.filename) as count
    from cd.tbl_1 s
    where s.dt like to_char(sysdate-1,'YYYYMMDD')||'%' and s.type='$i';
    exit;
    EOF)

this part is printing non-numeric values which is like below

COUNT ---------- 5663

that's why cannot any operation on those numbers. 

So how do i select only numbers "5663" ?
```

Comment: set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
that's it. Now it's working perfect